# How to force std::cin not to do any implicit conversion?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if we can force std::cin so it doesn't performs any implicit conversion between data types, for e.g:

```
unsigned int number;
cout<<"Please input a number :";
if(std::cin>>number)cout<<std::endl<<"Good number";
else cout<<"Bad number";
```

So if you punch -23 or 26.3 , it will simply perform implicit conversion and store the value in `number` which isn't I want. So can we stop this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you it to read from the stream if you enter `-23`? What do you expect?

Comment: read it as a string and validate the input yourself(?)

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you want to read a string?

Comment: @Mr. Anubis: would you want an exception instead of a silent conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin` is going to store the value into the data type you provide. `unsigned int` will not take `signed` numbers so it will overflow to the largest `unsigned int` or to `0`. In your example, you are providing a `double` constant, which is not an `unsigned int`. Change your `unsigned int` to a `double` if you want it to work the way you intended.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` will always perform that conversion; it's not something you can control. I would suggest reading the value into a string and checking it for `.` or `-`, then proceed from there.

Comment: Or read it into a string and use `strtol()` or `strtoul()` to parse it.

Comment: Or use boost::lexical_cast which will throw an exception if not all the data is used.